# jquery; django; parsing httpresponse

Tags: jquery, django, httpresponse

I have a problem with parsing http response.. I try send some values to client

`>>>>return HttpResponse(first=True,second=True)`

when parsing:

```
$.post('get_values',"",function(data){
                alert(data['first']); //The alert isn't shown!!!
            });
```

what is the right way to extract values from httpresponse

maybe I make a mistake when create my response..

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to use json, you could do something like this:

**Django**

```
data = json.dumps({"FIRST":True, "SECOND":False})
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json")
```

and get it as:

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON(url, [data], function(data){
                alert(data['first']);
            });
```

getJSON is a jquery shorthand function equivalent to the $.ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you made your HttpResponse json:

```
return HttpResponse("{\"first\":true,
\"second\":false}")
```

then you could receive it as json

```
$.post('get_values',"",function(data){
                alert(data['first']); //The alert isn't shown!!!
            },"json");
```